# What is the correct way to write this in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I am needing to write few methods: `value(x)`, `zero(a,b,e)`, `area(a,b)`, `derivative(x)`

```
class Funkcja

    def initialize(funkcja)
        @funkcja = funkcja
    end

    def value(x)
        @funkcja.call(x)
    end
end
```

This class will have to work over block which is an object from Proc

This is how I create that new object

```
f = Funkcja.new (Proc.new{|x| x*x*Math.sin(x)})
```

What is the correct way and in Ruby style (if not please show me that i
newbie in Ruby) to do this right `Funkcja.new (Proc.new x)` and
initialize `@funkcja = funkcja`

```
def zero(a, b, eps)
      x = (a+b)/2.0
      val = value(x)

      if val >= -eps and val <= eps
         x
      else
        left = value(a)
        rigth = value(b)
        if left < 0 and val > 0
            zero(a,x,eps)
        elsif left > 0 and val < 0
            zero(a,x,eps)
        elsif rigth > 0 and val < 0
            zero(x,b,eps)
        elsif rigth < 0 and val > 0
            zero(x,b,eps)
        elsif value == 0
            x
        else
            nil
        end
      end
  end

  def area(a,b)
    pole = 0
    while a < b
        if (self.value(a) > self.value( a + 0.00001))
            pole = pole + (self.value( a) * 0.00001)
        else
            pole = pole + (self.value( a + 0.00001) * 0.00001 )
        end
        a += 0.00001
    end
    pole
  end

  def derivative(x)
    eps = 0.00000001
    return (self.value(x) - self.value(x - eps))/eps
  end
```

Area is calculated area between `a` and `b` and `OX`, zero is find where
`F (x)=0` derivative is calculated as derivative in point.

Comment: What do those methods do? Is there any reason you can't define a normal method that takes a block instead of involving Proc? This example also pertains to `x` but it's not clear how the others become involved, like where do `a,b` come from?

Comment: I have to do this using block witch is object of Proc. Added def of methods

Answer (score 1):

The main thing that's non-idiomatic is this:

```
f = Funkcja.new (Proc.new{|x| x*x*Math.sin(x)})
```

What would be more normal is to do this:

```
f = Funkcja.new { |x| x*x*Math.sin(x) }
```

This is a normal block, and you could split it up among multiple lines as usual:

```
f = Funkcja.new do |x|
  x*x*Math.sin(x)
end
```

However, this wouldn't work with your `initialize` definition and that's because of one minor detail. You'd just need to change `def initialize(funkcja)` to `def initialize(&funkja)` - this converts the passed block into a proc that you can assign to a variable, use `call` with, etc:

```
def initialize(&funjka)
  @funkja = funkja
end
```

Another way to do the same thing would be this:

```
def initialize
  @funkja = yield
end
```

Other than that, your code seems fine with one other glaring non-idiomatic thing, which that you use `self.value`. The `self` is unnecessary unless you're using a setter method (i.e. `self.value =`), which you're not here.

Comment: Can you tell me how can i  extend class Proc in my task?

Comment: If I want extend class Proc using my methods how can i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here's an idea of adapting one of your methods to a more Ruby style:

```
def area(a,b)
  pole = 0

  while a < b
    if (yield(a) > yield(a + 0.00001))
      pole = pole + (yield(a) * 0.00001)        
    else
      pole = pole + (yield(a + 0.00001) * 0.00001)
    end

    a += 0.00001
  end

  pole
end
```

You'd use it like this:

```
area(a, b) do |a|
  a ** 2
end
```

Now it's one thing to be handling Proc objects, that's fine, the `do ... end` method of appending blocks to method calls generates those by default. It's very *not* Ruby to put extra methods on Proc itself. I can't see anything here that can't be covered by defining these inside a simple module:

```
module CalculationModule  
  def area(a, b)
    # ... Implementation
  end

  extend self
end
```

That way you can use those methods like `CalculationModule.area` or you can always `include` it into another class or module and use them like `area`.

Comment: But i need to write a class, how can i do it because i think my idea isnt to good.

Comment: The reason you'd use a class instead of a module is if you have instance variables that persist state between calls. I don't see any of that here.

Comment: I have a task to do where is said write a class so i dont have a choice.

Comment: Then call it `class` instead of `module`, but to use it you need to do `MyClass.new.area(...)`